# aws - ECS capacity provider permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I'm trying out teraform for managing my infrastructure and got into a bit of an issue and I'm not sure what to look for.

I'm attempting to create a capacity provider for my ECS cluster however I'm getting the following error

```
ClientException: The capacity provider could not be created because you do not have autoscaling:CreateOrUpdateTags permissions to create tags on the Auto Scaling group
```

Below are my files:

**Launch config and autoscale group creation**

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "ecs_launch_configuration" {
    name = "ecs_launch_configuration"
    image_id = "ami-0fe19057e9cb4efd8"
    user_data = "#!/bin/bash\necho ECS_CLUSTER=ecs_cluster >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config"
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.vpc_securityGroup.id]
    iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.iam_role_profile.name
    key_name = "key_pair_name"
    instance_type = "t2.small"
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "ecs_autoScale_group" {
    name                      = "ecs_autoScale_group"
    desired_capacity          = 1
    min_size                  = 1
    max_size                  = 2
    launch_configuration = aws_launch_configuration.ecs_launch_configuration.name
    vpc_zone_identifier = [aws_subnet.vpc_subnet_public.id]
    tag {
        key                 = "AmazonECSManaged"
        value               = true
        propagate_at_launch = true
    }
}
```

**ECS Cluster and capacity provider creation**

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "ecs_cluster"{
    name = "ecs_cluster"
    capacity_providers = [ aws_ecs_capacity_provider.ecs_capacity_provider.name ]
}

resource "aws_ecs_capacity_provider" "ecs_capacity_provider" {
    name = "ecs_capacity_provider"
    auto_scaling_group_provider {
        auto_scaling_group_arn = aws_autoscaling_group.ecs_autoScale_group.arn
        managed_scaling {
            maximum_scaling_step_size = 2
            minimum_scaling_step_size = 1
            status                    = "ENABLED"
            target_capacity           = 1
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to create this from the console's GUI, however only terraform returns this error.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

(a guess)

Isn't it because the IAM user you are using in your Terraform code is lacking the `autoscaling:CreateOrUpdateTags` permission?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-auto-scaling.html says:

> The IAM user creating the capacity providers, needs the autoscaling:CreateOrUpdateTags permission. This is because Amazon ECS adds a tag to the Auto Scaling group when it associates it with the capacity provider.

Comment: Yeah it would make sense, however it's the same user I'm using to login to the GUI console. Only difference is that with terraform, I'm using the access key and access key secret. The IAM user in question has the AdministratorAccess policy attached